# EF Core Scaffold-DbContext table not included in the selection set

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I recently upgraded to.Net Core 2.0, and I'm running into a lot of issues scaffolding an existing database.

First of all, when I run

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=mysrv;Database=mydb;User Id=uname;password=pword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I get the following errors. Which is really confusing me because there is no table in my database with a UK_principal_name index?

```
Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table dbo.sysdiagrams.
For index PK__sysdiagrams__0CBAE877. Unable to find parent table dbo.sysdiagrams. Skipping index.
For index UK_principal_name. Unable to find parent table dbo.sysdiagrams. Skipping index.
```

So I tried specifying a table I want from the database like this.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=mysrv;Database=mydb;User Id=uname;password=pword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Table Burner
```

And I get the errors I had before along with this error.

```
Index column dbo.BurnerHistory belongs to index PK_BurnerHistory on table Burn_Hist_Idx which is not included in the selection set. Skipping.
```

What does it mean when it says the table is not included in the selection set? On the previous version of .NET Core I had no problem running this scaffold command, it would grab all of my tables and generate code for them in the model.

Comment: I think it is warnings, not errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I'm using SQL server 2005, and Scaffold-Dbcontext has errors with dbo.sysdiagrams on that version. Had to go back to an older version of .NET.

These weren't just warnings, because I wasn't able to scaffold my model before I resolved this.